# When displaying a picture from the gallery, the application breaks down

Tags: java, android, image-gallery

sorry for my English.

The application worked properly. attached the file to imageview and then it was sent to the server.

And now after selecting a picture (file) the application displays it in the imageview all the methods work out correctly and to the end.

But the application throws me to the previous fragment without any errors in the log.

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100){

        if(getPath(data.getData()) != null){

        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        file = new File(getPath(fileUri));

        String mimetype = getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(fileUri);
        Log.d("mylog","name " + file.getName() + " type " + mimetype);

        imageV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageV.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons8highpriority96);

        if(mimetype.equals("image/jpeg")){ imageV.setImageURI(fileUri);}
        if(mimetype.equals("image/png")){ imageV.setImageURI(fileUri);}
        if(mimetype.equals("application/pdf")){ imageV.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons8pdf80);}
        if(mimetype.equals("text/html")){ imageV.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons8doc80);}

        textFileName.setText(file.getName());
        textFileName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }else {
            imageV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textFileName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textFileName.setText("Выберите файл из определенного раздела! ");}

    }

}
```

I attach some of the logs that confuse me -

```
447-705/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 
{act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=*/* 
cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery} from pid 
1382
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 34149 
to 23219
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 45759 
to 23219
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 37369 
to 23219
447-705/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 616K, 27% free 
6910K/9424K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
447-705/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 755K, 31% free 
6526K/9424K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 28979 
to 23219
447-540/system_process I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10016) 
res=-1 
errno=1
447-540/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: 
setKernelCountSet(10016, 1) failed with errno -1
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 662K, 
27% free 
3596K/4900K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 527K, 
28% free 
3547K/4900K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 31767 
to 23219
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 220K, 
27% free 
3613K/4900K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
447-464/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed 
com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: +124ms
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 103K, 
21% free 
3915K/4900K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 265K, 
16% free 
4121K/4900K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
1448-1448/com.android.gallery D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 586K, 
24% free 
3748K/4900K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default:  
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
447-540/system_process I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10053) 
res=-1 
errno=1
447-540/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: 
setKernelCountSet(10053, 0) failed with errno -1
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
447-539/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 999K, 31% free 
6545K/9424K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 44149 
to 23219
201-304/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 55759 
to 23219
447-447/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 444K, 27% free 
6903K/9424K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
447-447/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 749K, 31% free 
6525K/9424K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
447-544/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: 
setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
447-540/system_process I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10053) 
res=-1 
errno=1
447-540/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: 
setKernelCountSet(10053, 1) failed with errno -1
1382-1382/com.example.usersad.myapplication D/mylog: name 
IMG_20180327_045230.jpg type image/jpeg
```

I copied my code into a new project and it works!
both from activi and fragment.
but in the main project after interaction with the gallery the fragment is closed.

Comment: Where have you attached those logs?

Comment: i affixed  question

Comment: Your logcat has no information about the crash, please attach the relevant logcat

Comment: this is the whole problem. There are no critical errors. this log corresponds to the beginning of an error.
if you click "back" from the gallery or select a photo, the application breaks down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.
the application was closed because I called another fragment in the onStart method of the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code wrote inside the `onActivityResult` with `try`  and `cath` and print the exception

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to debug your code line by line, I think something is null. some time in different sdk ,get Path(file Uri) is different

Comment: I check for emptiness. if(getPath(data.getData()) != null). no?

Comment: yes is true but data.getData can be null and makes error. best way is debug. and put breakpoints in your if and inside if.

Comment: I output to getData and got the exact address of the photo

Comment: Ok, I'm still offering you debugging. with debugging that suspicious block , you will find your problem in a minute.

Comment: I do not understand yet how you want me to do it. if you can not be difficult, welcome an example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this structure. replace the variables and methods with your ones. Hope it will help you. Please comment for any query.

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        try {
            galleryopen = false;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            Consts.img_Bitmap = null;
            Consts.img_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropActivity.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_CAMERA) {
        try {
            galleryopen = false;

            Uri selectedImageUri = getImageUri();
            String uri = selectedImageUri.toString();

            Consts.img_Bitmap = null;
            Consts.img_Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);

            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImageUri.getPath());
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    Consts.img_Bitmap = rotateImage(Consts.img_Bitmap, 90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    Consts.img_Bitmap = rotateImage(Consts.img_Bitmap, 180);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    Consts.img_Bitmap = rotateImage(Consts.img_Bitmap, 270);
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            galleryopen = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        galleryopen = false;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you have not selected any Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I have this separate method. I must attach any file of any type. my code - String imageUri; Cursor cursor; CursorLoader loader; String[] data = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, data, null, null, null); cursor = loader.loadInBackground(); int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); cursor.moveToFirst(); imageUri = cursor.getString(column_index); loader.onCanceled(cursor); return imageUri;

Answer (score 0):

Try Editing  `AndroidManifest.xml` as mention below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tscolari.photo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PhotoFilterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: my manifest contains
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />